# Multiple definition of `Node::print()' in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, pragma

I'm trying to write a `List` class, but have a problem:

> E:\junior_req\test_project\Node.cpp|6|multiple definition of `Node::print()'|

My code:

Node.h:

```
class Node {
    Node* next;
    int value;
public:
    Node() {next = nullptr; value = 0;}
    Node(int t) {this->value = t; next = nullptr;}
    Node(const Node& t) {this->next = t.next; value = t.value;}
    ~Node() {}

    int getValue() {return value;}
    Node* getNext() {return next;}

    void setValue(int t) {value = t;}
    void setNext(Node* t) {next = t;}

    Node& operator=(Node t);

    void print();
};
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Node::print() {
    cout << this->getValue() << endl;
    if(this->getNext() != nullptr) this->getNext()->print();
}
```

List.h and List.cpp classes are same, but there are no errors.

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    List l;
    l.add(1);
    Node* one;
    l.add(one);
    one->print();
    return 0;
}
#endif // NODE_H
```

`#pragma once` doesn't help

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Neil this duplicate is wrong IMHO. There is no single template argument!

Comment: Your 'list.h' file is missing include guards (but your main.cpp has one, which is wrong).

Comment: Except for the include guard, there is nothing wrong with the code